# INSERT INTO dynamically added columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Running SQL Server 2005/2008, I am rewriting my query to be cleaner and more compliant to not include bad habits. I used to have lots of `IF` statements and `PIVOT` to do this, but found a better way to achieve it now and just need a last bit to make it almost perfect.

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME;
DECLARE @enddate DATETIME;
DECLARE @showstore INT;
DECLARE @showcashier INT;
DECLARE @showregister INT;
DECLARE @showdate INT;
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @result0 NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @startdate = '1/1/2012';
SET @enddate = '2/28/2013';
SET @showdate = 1;
SET @showstore = 0;
SET @showcashier = 1;
SET @showregister = 0;
SET @startdate = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @startdate), 0);
SET @enddate = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @enddate), 0);

SET @sql = N'CREATE TABLE ##a13 (' + SUBSTRING(
CASE WHEN @showdate = 1 THEN ',[Transaction Date] DATETIME' ELSE '' END + 
CASE WHEN @showstore = 1 THEN ',[Store ID] VARCHAR(10)' ELSE '' END + 
CASE WHEN @showcashier = 1 THEN ',[Cashier] VARCHAR(100)' ELSE '' END + 
CASE WHEN @showregister = 1 THEN ',[Register] VARCHAR(20)' ELSE '' END, 2, 2000);

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT c.CurrencyDesc 
    FROM dbo.Currencies AS c INNER JOIN dbo.rpPay AS p ON c.POSCurrency = p.PayType 
        INNER JOIN dbo.RPTrs AS r ON r.ReceiptNO = p.ReceiptNo
    WHERE
        c.CurrencyDesc <> 'Testing' AND c.CurrencyDesc <> 'Cash Change' AND
        r.TRSDate >= @startdate AND r.TRSDate <= @enddate
OPEN myCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @result0
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + ',[' + @result0 + '] INT'
        FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @result0
    END
CLOSE myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor

SET @sql = @sql + ')'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@startdate DATETIME, 
    @enddate DATETIME',@startdate, @enddate;

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ##a13; DROP TABLE ##a13'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

This Returns a table empty of rows. (know that the Currencies tables has more CurrencyDesc then shown here because these are just the ones used in the date range provided)

[image]

Which is exactly what I expect from it. Great so far so good. Now I need to add rows of data to it based on a Date Range (`@startdate >= and <= @enddate`) and depending on what they have checked off from the 4 possible options (`@showstore, @showcashier, @showdate, @showregister`)

Example : Date from 1/1/2013 till 2/28/2013 and show Register only (as seen in the picture) should have this DATA :

```
  | Register | Cash  | House Acct | MasterCard | Visa/MC
--------------------------------------------------------
1 | 01       | 20.00 | 235.25     | 1235.32    | 135.23
2 | 02       | 30.00 | 3542.42    | 323.52     | 523.64
3 | 03       | 23.35 | 100.32     | 3267.24    | 235.25
```

Reason for 2005/2008 is because some of the clients this is executed against, still use 2005 and in order to use `PIVOT` I would have to change the compatibility level on each database that is 2005.

PS. Before I get yelled at again, if I use #a13 instead of the global ##a13 it gives me

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Invalid object name '#a13'.
```

What can I do about that so I don't use global temp tables?

Comment: "Reason for 2005/2008 is because some of the clients this is executed against, still use 2005 and in order to use PIVOT I would have to change the compatibility level on each database that is 2005." Huh?

Comment: So are you asking how to not use a `##GLOBAL` temp table?

Comment: I am confused about your comment regarding `pivot`, both sql server 2005/2008 have the function.

Comment: in order to use `PIVOT` on a SQL 2005 i had to set the compatibility to 90. I rather not do that. 
@JNK - Yes, but that is a secondary question. Primary being, how do I add the data per row depending on the the selection

Comment: That warning about compatibility level in the MSDN docs is just for databases upgraded from older versions of SQL Server.  Do you have DBs in lower level compat modes?

Comment: @JohnZ what is the compatibility level of the db on the SQL 2005 instance?

Comment: @swasheck - Not sure atm... but it wasn't 90. Don't have a 2005 DB at hand right now to check. Is this a big issue where I should prefer to use `PIVOT` over `cursor`?

Comment: The Main question is how to add the data. The PIVOT/Global Temp is just extra stuff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I am incorrect here, please clarify.

I BELIEVE you are asking how to populate a table with dynamic columns based on user input.  The **right** answer here is, **don't do that!**

The best practice for this kind of thing is to have ALL the fields in your output table, then in your application/display layer you only show the fields that the user has requested.

Customizing a table layout within TSQL just to make a clean presentation introduces a lot of unnecessary complexity.  This complexity comes with an increased performance cost as well.

If you have a static output table then it's trivial to return your data using the parameters given.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that. Makes much more sense to do it that way.

Comment: @JohnZ Happy to help.  Always keep in mind the data layer doesn't have to match what the user sees, and it's much easier to do this sort of thing outside the DB.

Comment: Now how about the global temp table thing? how can I use temp tables with dynamic SQL without using globals?

Comment: @JohnZ You need to create the `#TEMP` table in the outer scope (stored proc) then insert into it in the inner scope.

Comment: `#TEMP` tables are only visible in the current scope and any nested scopes from current, so an outer scope (like a calling proc) couldn't see one that is created inside dynamic SQL

Comment: Thank you. Everything has worked for me as you said. Created a #temp with all the data outside of the dynamic SQL and then manipulated the select.